# Admob can not work with Android wear

Tags: admob, google-play-services, wear-os

I am writing an Android Wear application. I am using Andrid Studio 0.8.6. I want to add Admob to this app. But I found that I can't add following 2 lines in the same build.gradle:

```
...
dependencies {
...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'
}
```

This will cause following compilation error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:processDebugResources'.
> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'
You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0
```

If I remove "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'" line, the project can be compiled, but "AdActivity" in AndroidManifest.xml is red:

```
...
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
...
```

This means AdActivity can not be resolved. How can I add Admob to an Android Wear project? Please advise. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The `play-services-wearable` seem to be a special version of the Google Play Services which include only the most necessary parts. So I guess they don't have something like **Google Analytics**, **Admob** etc. on board though I can't find any reference for this assumption.

In terms of your error: The `play-services-wearable` and `play-services` share some components. So in order to avoid this error you should remove the "lightweight" `play-services-wearable` instead of the extensive `play-services`.

Comment: If I remove play-services-wearable, the wearable related features have problems. I think this may be a bug either for Android Studio or Google Play Service. They may have to provide a "full" services version which contains all the service in on package to solve this package conflict issue.

Comment: Ahh okay. I just tried it and Android Studio didn't complain so I assumed this would work. I think we have to wait and see if Google adds Analytics / Admob to the Play Services for the wearable.

Comment: I wouldn't hold your breath waiting for that to happen. I suspect it will never be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the problem the fact that wearable devices cannont connect to the Internet ? For everything Internet related you must use your handheld device as a proxy...

Comment: If you remove wearable from dependencies, the handheld can not send message to wearable device. If you remove google play service, com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity can be resolved. If you keep both, the compilation error happens. And I even can't find where to set android.enforceUniquePackageName=false. Does anybody know?

Comment: I think as reVerse said the problem is that Admob isn't in the `play-services-wearable`. As I told you I think it's because the wearable device isn't able to connect to the Internet directly. You should wait for a wearable implemetation of admob who will can use the handheld device as a proxy.